# dynamic-dropdown select button but no caret

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-select

I can't for the life of me figure out how to get my caret to show up.  I noticed that in Safari my select dropdown had a glossy style while the others were picking up the flat-ui.css.  In Chrome they're all flat.  So I've been messing with the data-toggle, when I do the caret disappears.  I can't seem to get the dropdown to be both flat AND have the caret.

I've tried adding a  in the  block but no dice.  Nothing shows up.  Looking in dev tools on Chrome, it says it's picking up the styling from user agent.  So maybe I have to reset the default css?

I dunno, I'm at a loss.  Please help.

```
 <h3 class="demo-panel-title">Taxonomy</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
    <select class="form-control btn btn-primary" data-toggle="select" id="example" data-selected-text-format="count">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B » B1 </option>
    <option value="C">C » C1</option>
</select>
    </div> <!-- /.col-xs-6 -->
    </div> <!-- /.row -->
  <h3 class="demo-panel-title"></h3>
```

Comment: Are you using plugin?

Comment: I'm using this for dynamic dropdown https://gist.github.com/jayalfredprufrock/1356298

Comment: This is what I have to call the plugin.  `<script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.dynamicDropdown.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">jQuery("#example").dynamicDropdown({"delimiter":" » "});</script>`

Comment: can we get a live example or fiddle?

Comment: try this- https://jsfiddle.net/mafiata/4n21mwqu/4/

Comment: removing the dynamic dropdown still causes the issue.  the caret in the span just won't show up